# Why is trim() returning an empty string if it receives a multiline string (containing CR)?

Tags: powershell

When I pass a multiline string (containing at least one carriage return), the 'comment' is empty. Is there a solution for that?

```
$comment = ($input | where {$_.trim() -ne ""})
```

Comment: Could you show complete example necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Careful using `$input` its a reserved variable. Can you show us an [mcve] for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line fixed the problem:

```
$comment = @($input)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$comment = foreach($line in $input) {$line.trim()}
```

Comment: Shouldn't $input be included?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
$comment = ($input -split "`r?`n") | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne "" }
```

What this line does is remove all CRLF